# Unable to create NSMutableArray using for-loop

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

i want to have an array with values "25 kg", "26 kg"... "149 kg", "150 kg". To simplify task i wrote this:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)weightArray{

    NSMutableArray *myArray;
    for (int i=25; i++; i<150){
        NSString *weightString;
        weightString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d kg", i];
        [myArray addObject:weightString];
    }
    return myArray;
}
```

And then in viewDidload in my view i wrote: `NSLog (@"%@", [self weightArray]);`
But it looks like it's not working. I might be missing something obvious like syntax. Why is it not working?

UPDATE:
Finally i found a solution - first, i declare weightArray in @implementation section, then i wrote:

```
-(void)fillingArray{

    if (!weightArray){
        for (int i=25; i<150 ;i++){
            NSString *weightString = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            weightString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d kg", i];
            [weightArray addObject:weightString];
            NSLog(@"%@", weightString);
        }
    }

}
```

In viewDidLoad i wrote:

```
[self fillingArray];  
 NSLog(@"%@", weightArray);
```

I think, my problem was in that string NSLog(@"%@", [self weightArray]); In square brackets it suppose to be method name, but i was trying to point at array, and nothing happening.

Comment: You have to init your array.

Comment: It is bad form to change your question (especially the code) over time. It invalidates the answers you get. If anything, add an update to the end of your question.

Comment: Why are people voting to close this question? It is a perfectly valid question that can be answered in its current form.

Comment: I agree rmaddy.  Thankfully the up-votes weigh more than the down.

Comment: You still haven't initialized the array. You blindly copied the invalid code that Jeff had in his answer (before he fixed it). Please understand the code, don't just copy it.

Comment: If the code is not working, make sure you still have your NSLog (@"%@", [self weightArray]); in your viewDidLoad

Comment: I actually did remove that, i just copy past code below to see if i can solve problem, later fix that

Comment: Why was this question closed?  It was a legitimate question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 3 problems with what you are doing.

1. You need to create your array like this: `NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` so that it will actually exist.
2. Your `NSLog` needs to be `NSLog (@"%@", [self weightArray]);` since you are lgging an array and not a number.
3. (thanks rmaddy for pointing this out)   The 2nd and 3rd part of your `for` statement are reversed.  So, `i++` is your condition and is always non-zero.  This infinite loop is what causes your machine to lock up.

EDIT: Here's a better way that only creates the array once.

```
-(NSMutableArray*)weightArray{

    static NSMutableArray *myArray;
    if (!myArray){
        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i=25; i<150 ;i++){
            NSString *weightString;
            weightString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d kg", i];
            [myArray addObject:weightString];
        }
    }
    return myArray;
}
```

Comment: I see that you modified your question to address my second point.

Comment: I also see another problem with this approach: 3. This array is created every time this method is called... can be processor expensive. Why not create this array in `init` instead and assign to an ivar or property?

Comment: Issue 4: The `for` loop is written incorrectly. The 2nd and 3rd parts are reversed.

Comment: I don't like the `static` variable you used as this would remain in memory essentially for the life of the app (maybe this isn't a problem, perhaps, but it is definitely a consequence of your approach). Also, you never actually `alloc` and `init` this variable in your code snippet, so it will have the same problem you list as 1.

Comment: Yes, it's a trade-off between keeping the data in memory or running the for-loop every time. Keeping it in memory is bettor for battery while allowing the loop to run every time is better for memory pressure. If you know ahead of time that the array will always be the same, it would be better to hard-code this as a constant as this keeps it in the code space instead of the heap.

Comment: Jeff i did what you told me, but why i cant see array values with  NSLog(@"%@", [self weightArray]); in console?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Unlike the code in Jeff's answer, please make sure you initialize the array like he state's in issue #1.

Comment: That's what I get for doing a blind copy-paste.  Fixed.  Thanks rmaddy, again.

Comment: @JeffWolski Not fixed. You nuked the string.

Comment: Ok, I should not be on here today.  I also misspelled a variable name.  It's fixed for real now, and I pasted it into Xcode to check myself.

Comment: No, even when i wrote myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; and NSLog as you said. Still it works a way i did with void function, but why not with array..

Answer (score 2):

You don't allocate and initialize the array. So it has an indeterminate value, and your program invokes undefined beahvior. Create it actually:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Comment: Thank you, but it get worse when i allocate it with [[NSMutableArray alloc]init], now it never load screen and freeze whole Mac, weird..

Comment: It's not actually a memory management issue.  See part 3 of my answer.  -Cheers.